# How to merge PHP multidimensional array keeping a unique key and separating with comma the other value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I want to make it matching the "unique key" value but merge the other key that has the same "unique key" value, it could be speared by comma, since my final output will be to use `json_encode`.

So for instance, if I have:

```
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "123"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "124"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "126"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "129"
      }
      [4]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "130"
      }
      [5]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "102"
      }
      [6]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "193"
      }
      [7]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "AB"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "156"
      }
      [8]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "BG"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "246"
      }
      [9]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(1) "C"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "234"
      }
      [10]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(1) "C"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "235"
      }
      [11]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "CA"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "345"
      }
      [12]=>
      array(2) {
        ["label"]=>
        string(2) "CA"
        ["value"]=>
        string(8) "564"
     }
```

And I want an output like:

```
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(2) "AB"
    ["value"]=>
    string "123,124,126,129,130,102,193,156“
  }
    [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(2) "BG"
    ["value"]=>
    string "246"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(1) "C"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "234,235,”
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(2) "CA"
    ["value"]=>
    string(8) "345,564,”
  }
```

I am not sure how to do it, I've looked into [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) and other similar solutions, but I did not got it, maybe I need to use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $arr) {
    if (!isset($result[$arr['label']])) {
        $result[$arr['label']] = $arr;
        continue;
    }

    $result[$arr['label']]['value'] .= ',' . $arr['value'];
}

// if you really need numeric indexes use:

$result = array_values($result);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved for me! Also you give a fast reply, thanks 

Comment: Oh I've noticed it's almost perfect, I've lost the format like Label =>  AB, Valeu =>123,345
I will try to figure out it, thanks for your help

Comment: I’ve fixed my problem by adding a sorting before, it was my fault. Your code is perfect, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'label' => "AB",
        'value' => 123
    ),
    array(
        'label' => "AB",
        'value' => 124
    ),
    array(
        'label' => "AB",
        'value' => 125
    ),
    array(
        'label' => "C",
        'value' => 126
    ),
    array(
        'label' => "C",
        'value' => 127
    ),
    array(
        'label' => "C",
        'value' => 127
    ),
);

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $el) {
    $result[$el['label']] = array(
        'label' => $el['label'],
        'value' => implode( ',',
            array_unique(
                array_merge(
                    array_filter(
                        explode(',', $result[$el['label']]['value'])
                    ),
                    array($el['value'])
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

echo "<pre>"; var_dump(array_values($result));
```